# MVC Core Select Tag not updating Field Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an application with a drop-down menu and I want the selected value from the drop-down to update my Model, but for some reason it won't. I'm always getting empty value when routing to my IActionResult method.

Model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> MyNames { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
    <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label col-md-3"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <select asp-for="Name" asp-items="Model.MyNames" class="form-control"></select>
        </div>
        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>

    <span class="text-right">
                    <a class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" type="submit"
                       asp-action="LoadData"
                       asp-controller="MyController" ,
                       asp-route-Name="@Name">Load Person</a>
                </span>
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Create()
    {
        var names = GetNamesFromFile(fileName);

        var myModel = new MyModel();

        foreach (var name in names)
        {
            myModel.MyNames.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = name, Text = name});
        }
        return View(myModel);
    }

public IActionResult LoadData(string Name)
    {
       var person = GetPersonByName(Name); 

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index), "MyController", new { id = template.PersonId });
    }
```

When I route back to my ActionResult, I expect the Name parameter to have the value I set in the drop-down menu. The code seems fine to me, I can't figure out why it won't work.

EDIT: Apparently, the problem lies with the Submit button. If I use an href tag, the form won't submit and the drop-down list won't get called at all. Is there any way to make this work an href tag by any chance?

Comment: How are you posting the data to your controller? can you provide an example containing your controller?

Comment: Looks like you're fetching the names from the file each time, where are you saving the changed name?

Comment: I tried adding a property public SelectedName {get;set;} and use that for the drop-down menu, but it wouldn't update either. Do I need to do something in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're doing 2 mistakes:

1) According to [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a), `<a>` tag's `type` attribute used to specify MIME type of a media for resource which linked to the URL. It never intended to perform submit with form elements, including `<select>` element. Hence, `Name` property value is never changed while redirecting to `LoadData` action.

2) The page doesn't specify any `<form>` element/tag helper used to submit the selected value from `<select>` element. A form submit is necessary to send its value back to controller action method.

The fixed page markup should be look like this:

```
<form asp-controller="MyController" asp-action="LoadData" method="get">
    <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label col-md-3"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <select asp-for="Name" asp-items="Model.MyNames" class="form-control"></select>
        </div>
        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>

    <span class="text-right">
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Load Person</button>
    </span>
</form>
```

By using above setup, `Name` parameter should contain updated value from `<select>` element because form contents will be sent as query string.